# WPF Statusbar update for each line read using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#

After several hours of failing.  I'm at the point where I need some guidance.

Currently I'm parsing through a StreamReader with line items that can be in the thousands.  I added a Status Bar and wanted the bar to move +1 for each item.

I've been trying to learn how to do this with using a Background worker and now I think I got myself all twisted around. My code isn't breaking but the status bar isn't moving.  Either I'm using the wrong technique all together or I just need some tweaking.

```
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            fileProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
        void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(20);  // I just added a dummy value to get something.
        }
        void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Canceled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Worker Task Canceled.");
            }

            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker Task Error.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker Task Completed.");
            }
        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            filePath                     = @"C:\test.txt";
            worker.DoWork               += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
            worker.ProgressChanged      += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Worker_ProgressChanged);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted   += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                var parts = new List<Part>();
                var myCounter = 0;
                fileProgressBar.Maximum = filePath.Length;

                while (true)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    parts.Add(new Part(line, config));                      
                }
            }           
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: What is the `Minimum` and `Maximum` of the progress bar? By default they are 0 and 1, respectively, so if you're repeatedly setting `Value` to higher than one, those changes aren't going to visually register.

Comment: fileProgressBar.Maximum = filePath.Length;   I've set the max to the total count of the contents in the file.   My understanding of this is wrong.  It should be 100?  Or should I leave it out all togther?

Comment: Wait, I just realized that you are doing the work of loading the actual file on the UI thread, making your `BackgroundWorker` functionally useless. That `using` block and everything in it should be in the `DoWork` method, not in the `Button_Click` method.